# Overlay box plots and add a line using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame like this

```
data = as.data.frame(data.table::rbindlist(PLOTS))

head(data)
    Y              X     dep_C1

   3.96655960      0     184
  -8.71308460      0     184
 -11.11638947      0     184
  -6.84213562      11    184
  -1.25926609      11    184
  -4.60649529      11    184
   0.27577858      11    184
  11.85394249      20    184
  -0.27114563      20    184
   1.73081284      20    184
   1.78209915      20    184
  11.34305840      20    184
  13.49688263      20    184
  -7.54752045      20    184
 -13.63673286      25    184
  -5.75711517      25    184
   0.35823669      25    184
  -2.45237694      25    184
   0.49313087      0     66
  -9.04148674      0     66
 -15.50337906      0     66
 -17.51445351      0     66
 -10.66807098      0     66
  -2.24337845      5     66
 -13.79929533      5     66
   1.33287125      5     66
   2.22143402      5     66
  11.46484833      10    66
  23.26805916      10    66
   9.07377968      10    66
   4.28664665      10    66
```

I am trying to create two box plots for the two `dep_C1` values and overlay them. I tried with this

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(X), y=Y, colour = factor(dep_C1))) 
+ geom_boxplot(outlier.size=0,fill = "white") 
+ stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="line", aes(group=1,colour = factor(dep_C1)),size=2)
```

These are my problems

1) The two box plots are side by side and not overlaid

2) The command that draw a line between the medians is not working OK: lines should connect medians of boxplots of the same group (with only one boxplot is fine)

3) The values on the x axis are messed up (the series start again after 96)

Can someone help me fix these problems? Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Well, could you please illustrate the question #2: do I understand correctly, that you want boxplots of the same group to be connected? Could you add a reproducible example (possibly with the picture), what do you mean by "OK"?

Comment: To #3: why then the data is not merged into a single boxplot at point 0, for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first two problems are easy to fix. To overlay the boxplots, you want to specify `position="identity"` and probably something like `alpha=0.5`. For the line, the group should be `group=factor(dep_C1)`. Together this will look as follows:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(X), y=Y, colour = factor(dep_C1)))  +
 geom_boxplot(outlier.size=0, fill = "white", position="identity", alpha=.5)  +
 stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="line", aes(group=factor(dep_C1)), size=2)
```

For the 3rd question, you are using `factor(X)`, which defines the scale of the axis. You can change this scale using `scale_x_discrete`. Perhaps you are looking for something like the following:

```
scale_x_discrete(limits=seq(min(data$X), max(data$X)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix to the third problem is best solved if you convert X to continuos scale and not a factor; to make a box plot, though, you'll need `group = interaction(time, group)` is `aes`:

```
ggplot(data_frame_test, aes(x=time, y=Value, colour = factor(group), group = interaction(time, group)))  +
 geom_boxplot(outlier.size=0, fill = "white", position="identity", alpha=.5)  +
 stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="line", aes(group=factor(group)), size=2)
```